# jQuery get parsererror but status is 200 from Perl

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, perl

I have got a problem about the Ajax always got "textStatus: parsererror, errorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :",

However, the response is "responseText: {"success":"Search Successful","Timetable":"aaa"},"

I have searched on the website jsonlint.com it shows the JSON is valid.

Note: the "aaa" was the string I want to return, I wonder it may too long so changed it to "aaa", but the error still get.

Here is the code from Ajax

```
    $.ajax({
    type:"Get",
    url:"cgi-bin/timetable.pl",
    contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    data:"username="+username,
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown)
    {
        $('div#result').text(result);
        $('div#result').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText 
        + ", textStatus: " + textStatus 
        + ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        $('div#result').addClass("error");
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
        if (data.error) 
        {
            $('div#result').text("data.error: " + data.error);
            $('div#result').addClass("error");
        }
        else
        {
            $('div#result').text("data.success: " + data.success 
                + ", data.userid: " + data.clasinfo);
            $('div#result').addClass("success");
        }
    }
  })
```

Here is the Perl's

```
    foreach $classid(@claid)
    {
$class->execute($classid);
while (@cinfo = $class->fetchrow_array())
{
    $num = @cinfo;
    $combineinfo = "";
    for ($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
    {
         $combineinfo .= $cinfo[$i]."V";
    }
}
 push(@info,$combineinfo); 
 }

 $json = (@info)?
 qq{{"success":"Search Successful","Timetable":"'@info"}}:
 qq{{"error":"Search Error"}};


 print $cgi->header(-type => "application/json", -charset => "utf-8");
 print $json;
```

Comment: Why is there a single quote before @info? A copy'n'paste error?

Comment: It just a mistake....because I want to try '@info' is okay or not...

Comment: And Only When the return type is 'undefined' this could back to success...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing your own JSON, let perl encode it for you.

```
use JSON::PP;

my $response = (@info)?
    {"success" => "Search Successful", "Timetable" => @info}:
    {"error" => "Search Error"};

my $json = JSON::PP->new->allow_nonref;
print $json->encode($response);
```

Comment: :( I guess my perl does not support JSON:PP? it shows 500 http error when I refresh pl webpage...

Comment: I'm on perl 5.4.2 on Ubuntu

Comment: ...I am using school's computer and network so I could not setup any thing I want. So is there any solution? Only undefined type is successful...